# Creating deb package with debconf postints

Tags: linux, bash, templates, deb, debconf

I am begginer in creating deb packgaes. I created deb package with answers for user. But when i run `sudo apt install ./mypackge.deb`

I get the same errors

```
 Setting up test (0.0) ...
Can't exec "/var/lib/dpkg/info/test.config": No such file or directory at /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl-base/IPC/Open3.pm line 178.
open2: exec of /var/lib/dpkg/info/test.config configure  failed: No such file or directory at /usr/share/perl5/Debconf/ConfModule.pm line 59.
dpkg: error processing package test (--configure):
 installed test package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 2
```

My debian/config

```
#!/bin/sh
# Source debconf library.
. /usr/share/debconf/confmodule
set -e # fail on any error
set -u # treat unset variables as errors

# ======[ Trap Errors ]======#
set -E # let shell functions inherit ERR trap
# Trap non-normal exit signals:
# 1/HUP, 2/INT, 3/QUIT, 15/TERM, ERR
trap err_handler 1 2 3 15 ERR
function err_handler {
local exit_status=${1:-$?}
logger -s -p "syslog" -t  "TEST script '$0' error code $exit_status (line $BASH_LINENO: '$BASH_COMMAND')"
exit $exit_status
}
 

# Ask questions
db_set  test/migrate1 no
db_set  test/migrate2 no
db_input critical test/migrate1 || true
db_input critical test/migrate2 || true

# Show interface
db_go


exit 0
```

debian/templates

```
Template: test/migrate1
Type: select
Choices: yes, no
Default: no
Description: Create default schema?
 Create schema

Template: test/migrate2
Type: select
Choices: yes, no
Default: no
Description: Upload fixtures?
 Upload fixtures
```

My  debian/postinst

```
#!/bin/bash
export DEBCONF_DEBUG=developer

. /usr/share/debconf/confmodule

set -e # fail on any error
set -u # treat unset variables as errors
# ======[ Trap Errors ]======#
set -E # let shell functions inherit ERR trap
# Trap non-normal exit signals:
# 1/HUP, 2/INT, 3/QUIT, 15/TERM, ERR
trap err_handler 1 2 3 15 ERR
function err_handler {
local exit_status=${1:-$?}
logger -s -p "syslog" -t  "SYMFONY script '$0' error code $exit_status (line $BASH_LINENO: '$BASH_COMMAND')"
exit $exit_status
}

#Clean db if purge
if [ "$1" == "purge" ] && [ -e /usr/share/debconf/confmodule ] ; then
. /usr/share/debconf/confmodule
db_purge
fi


#Settingup DB
mysql -e "CREATE USER IF NOT EXISTS 'symfony'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED  BY '123456';"
mysql -e "CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS symfony CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci;"
mysql -e "GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON symfony.* TO 'symfony'@'localhost';"
 
# Fetching configuration from debconf
case "$1" in 
    install|upgrade)
                    
        db_get test-symfony/migrate1
            if [ "$RET" == "yes" ]; then
            cd /var/www/test-symfony/bin
            ./console doctrine:schema:create
            fi
            
    ;;      
    abort-upgrade)      
    ;;
    
    *)
        echo "preinst called with unknown argument \$1'" >&2
        exit 0
    ;;
    
esac

case "$1" in
    configure)
        db_get test-symfony/migrate2
            if [ "$RET" == "yes" ]; then
            cd /var/www/test-symfony/bin
            ./console doctrine:fixtures:upload
            fi
            echo "you have entered ::$RET" >&2
    ;;
esac    

#Settingup permissions and service
chown nginx:nginx /var/www/test.com
chown nginx:nginx /var/cache/ngx_pagespeed
sleep 2
sudo systemctl enable nginx.service
sudo systemctl start  nginx.service
sudo systemctl is-enabled  nginx.service



exit 0
```

I've tried different variants of config/postinst,used example from debconf manual, but have got the same error.

```
 Can't exec "/var/lib/dpkg/info/test.config.....
```

It would be good if you point on my mistakes out. Thnaks

Answer (score 0):

I'd assume your `.deb` is missing the `config` maintainer script (and possibly the `templates` file too). You can check with `dpkg-deb -I test.deb`.